# How to use debounce with Tiptap

Tags: reactjs, debouncing, tiptap

I am using Next in the frontend, convex in the backend to build a text editor.
Till now, I have made it so that when there is any update in the editor, I am updating the updated content to the database with mutations.
But the problem arises when I try to add debounce to it, since I wouldn't want the database to be updated with each keyPress, so I implemented this

```
const debounce = require("lodash.debounce");

  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    onUpdate: debounce(({ editor }: { editor: any }) => {
      updateContent({
        documentId: document?.[0]?._id as Id<"aipen">,
        content: editor?.getHTML(),
      });
    }, 2000),
  });
```

It should only call the `updateContent` when there is a gap of 2000 ms between two keyPress, but it is rather calling it on every keyPress or update in the editor.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to assign the debounced function to a variable on the top level:

```js
const debounce = require("lodash.debounce");

const debouncedOnUpdate = debounce(({ editor }: { editor: any }) => {
    updateContent({
        documentId: document?.[0]?._id as Id<"aipen">,
        content: editor?.getHTML(),
    });
}, 2000);

const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [StarterKit],
    onUpdate: debouncedOnUpdate,
});
```

Otherwise debounce has no way to keep a state that can keep track of the time.

Comment: This would definitely work.